# Replacing a value based on the across function in dplyr

Tags: r, mutate

Example dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)    

data <- data.frame(
l = c(NA, 2, NA, 4),
m = c(5, NA, 7, NA),
n = c(NA, 10, NA, NA),
o = c(6, 7, NA, 8),
y = c(2, 3, 4, 5))
```

So I need to replace the first value which is non "NA" in each row, when it comes up in sequence across four rows l to 0.
I want to replace the first non-NA value with a new value which is the product of the original first non_NA value and the value in column y.

I've tried using dplyr to run the following:

```
result <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    first_non_na_value = first(na.omit(c_across(l:o))),
    replaced_value = ifelse(
      !is.na(first_non_na_value),
      first_non_na_value * y,
      first_non_na_value
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

However this gives me two new columns which I don't need. I only want the new "replaced_values" to actually replace the first value that is not NA that occurs left to right in columns l:o in each row. I can't find a way to define which column value value is being replaced, as the column will change depending on where the first(na.omit(c_across(l:o))) value arises.

the expected result should look like this:

```
result <- data.frame(
l = c(NA, 6, NA, 20),
m = c(10, NA, 28, NA),
n = c(NA, 10, NA, NA),
o = c(6, 7, NA, 8),
y = c(2, 3, 4, 5))

result
```

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: include your expected results in the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather roundabout tidyverse solution. I'm sure there's something more concise and elegant.

1. Pivot the data to a long format and group by `y`
2. Find the index (row) of the first non-NA value by group
3. Compare the index with the row number by group and if they match, calculate the product, otherwise keep the original value
4. Select the required columns and pivot back to the wide format

Putting that together:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-y) %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(i = which.min(is.na(value)), 
         r = row_number(), 
         newval = ifelse(i == r, y * value, value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(y, name, newval) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = newval)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
      y     l     m     n     o
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
      2    NA    10    NA     6
      3     6    NA    10     7
      4    NA    28    NA    NA
      5    20    NA    NA     8
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This might be the approach to take with some tweaks, but this particular solution would only work if "y" is a unique value to each row I think. In my actual dataset there will be about 100 rows, and "y" will range between 0 and 1 in single digit decimals (0.0-1.0) so they will not be unique values.

Comment: What about something along ```t <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(first=first(na.omit(c_across(l:o))),
         column=match(first,c_across(l:o))
  )```to get the index of the column that needs to be altered? Furthermore, ```dplyr:::coalesce```might be handy here.

Comment: thanks, this was great, and I added to it by using a for loop to repeat a replacement in each row Thanks for you help. that was great. I built on this by adding a for loop:  


for (i in 1:nrow(t)) {
  column_index <- t$column[i] 
  y <- t$y[i]    
  new_value <- t$first[i] * y 
  t[i, column_index] <- new_value
}

Comment: Update your example data with something more realistic and we can try again.

Answer (score 0):

Great to be of help here! I'm quite sure your could solve that with an `*apply` function instead of a for-loop. Likely `sapply` would work, but I don't get my head around how I would solve that easily.
Additionally, I couldn't get `dplyr::coalesce` working the same way it works here. `coalesce(l,m,n,o)` would do the job, but `coalesce(l:o)` doesn't.
So quick and dirty, for few rows, here with a slightly different input.

```
data <- data.frame(
  l = c(NA, 2, NA, 4, NA),
  m = c(5, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  n = c(NA, 10, NA, NA, 3),
  o = c(6, 7, NA, 8, 5),
  y = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 2))

library(dplyr)

t <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    first_non_na_value = first(na.omit(c_across(l:o)))
    ,column_index=match(first_non_na_value,c_across(l:o))
    ,replaced_value = ifelse(
      !is.na(first_non_na_value),
      first_non_na_value * y,
      first_non_na_value
    )
  )

for (i in 1:nrow(t)) { 
  t[i,t$column_index[i]] <- t[i,"replaced_value"]
}

t %>% select(-c(first_non_na_value,column_index,replaced_value))
```

Input

```
   l  m  n  o y
1 NA  5 NA  6 2
2  2 NA 10  7 3
3 NA NA NA NA 4
4  4 NA NA  8 5
5 NA NA  3  5 2
```

Result

```
   l  m  n  o y
1 NA 10 NA  6 2
2  6 NA 10  7 3
3 NA NA NA NA 4
4 20 NA NA  8 5
5 NA NA  6  5 2
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best, but here is another approach

```r
data <- data.frame(
  l = c(NA, 2, NA, 4),
  m = c(5, NA, 7, NA),
  n = c(NA, 10, NA, NA),
  o = c(6, 7, NA, 8),
  y = c(2, 3, 4, 5)
) %>% mutate(new = coalesce(l, m, n, o),
             new2 = new * y,
             across(l:o, ~ ifelse(.x == new, new2, .x))) %>%
  select(-c(new, new2))
```

```r
   l  m  n  o y
1 NA 10 NA  6 2
2  6 NA 10  7 3
3 NA 28 NA NA 4
4 20 NA NA  8 5
```